# How to simplify several methods with similar bodies into one?

Tags: java, rest, exception, overriding

I would like to simplify my code and merge common parts of the several methods into new one. Could you give me the piece of advice - what is the best way to do it?
My methods are:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ProhibitedScimTypeException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> policyConflict(final ProhibitedScimTypeException exception) {
    final var errorDto = new ErrorDto();
    errorDto.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
    errorDto.setStatus(BAD_REQUEST.toString());
    errorDto.setScimType("prohibited");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = {UserAlreadyExistsException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> userNameExistsConflict(final UserAlreadyExistsException exception) {
    final var errorDto = new ErrorDto();
    errorDto.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
    errorDto.setStatus(CONFLICT.toString());
    errorDto.setScimType("uniqueness");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = {UserNotFoundException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> userNameNotFoundConflict(final UserNotFoundException exception) {
    final var errorDto = new ErrorDto();
    errorDto.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
    errorDto.setStatus(NOT_FOUND.toString());
    errorDto.setScimType("prohibited");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I would like to separate the common part which is:

```
final var errorDto = new ErrorDto();
errorDto.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
errorDto.setStatus(MEHTOD.toString());
errorDto.setScimType("something");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you extract the common part to a method like this?

```
private ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> conflict(final Throwable exception, HttpStatus status, String scrimType) {
    final var errorDto = new ErrorDto();
    errorDto.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
    errorDto.setStatus(status.toString());
    errorDto.setScimType(scrimType);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, status);
}
```

and call it from your methods,

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ProhibitedScimTypeException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> policyConflict(final ProhibitedScimTypeException exception) {
    return conflict(exception, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "prohibited");
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = {UserAlreadyExistsException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> userNameExistsConflict(final UserAlreadyExistsException exception) {
    return conflict(exception, HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "uniqueness");
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = {UserNotFoundException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> userNameNotFoundConflict(final UserNotFoundException exception) {
    return conflict(exception, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "prohibited");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method:

```java
    private ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> conflict(final Throwable exception, final Object status, final String scimType, final HttpStatus httpStatus) {
      final var errorDto = new ErrorDto();
      errorDto.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
      errorDto.setStatus(status.toString());
      errorDto.setScimType(scimType);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, httpStatus);
    }
```

and use it like

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ProhibitedScimTypeException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> policyConflict(final ProhibitedScimTypeException exception) {
      return this.conflict(exception, BAD_REQUEST, "prohibited", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```